# How to set args from chromeOptions in beforeSession webdriverIO+Cucumber

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, webdriver-io, cucumberjs

I need to install args before the session. On a specific tag must be transmitted a specific screen resolution. I tried to implement beforeSession, but the necessary arg is not in chromeOptions.args when starting the session.

I tried two version:

1.
beforeSession:

```
   beforeSession: function(){

        if(argv.tags ===("@virtualFront")){
            exports.config.capabilities[0].chromeOptions.args.push('--window-size=1080,1920');
        } else{
            exports.config.capabilities[0].chromeOptions.args.push(' --start-maximized');

        }
        console.log("it is from config beforeSession: "+exports.config.capabilities[0].chromeOptions.args);

    },
```

suite.cucumber.wdio.conf:

```
 browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ['--incognito',],
                binary: '/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe' 
            },
```

2. BeforeSession:

   beforeSession: function(){

   ```
       if(argv.tags ===("@virtualFront")){
           argv.optionChrome = '--window-size=1080,1920';
       } else{
           argv.optionChrome=' --start-maximized';
       }
       console.log("it is from config beforeSession: "+exports.config.capabilities[0].chromeOptions.args);
   },
   ```

suite.cucumber.wdio.conf:

```
 {
            browserName: 'chrome',
            chromeOptions: {
                args: ['--incognito',argv.optionChrome, ],
                binary: '/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
        },
```

When I use 2 version args asigned to null

Comment: When I run tests, browser open without arg with beforeSession, but console log print `it is from config beforeSession: --incognito, --start-maximized`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to add the script to the beginning of suite.cucumber.wdio.conf:

```
let chromeOpts = ['--incognito'];
if (argv.tags ==="@virtualFont"){
    chromeOpts +=` --window-size=1080,1920`
}else chromeOpts +=` --start-maximized`;
```

and:

```
chromeOptions: {
                args: [ chromeOpts, ],
                binary: '/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'
 //for windows7
            },
```